# SQL Delight Plugin is not found in Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, sqldelight

SQL Delight Plugin is not found in Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1. It is not a critical issue for me but I would like to know. I visited [JetBrains website](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8191-sqldelight/versions#tabs) but it seems there is no compatibility with the Dolphin Version.

I search in the Android Studios Plugins (Both Marketplace and Installed) and I checked all the compatible versions in Jetbrains's website.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is no support for Dolphin as I can see on the plugin page. However you can upgrade your Android Studio to Electric Eel Version, then you would be able to download this plugin.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8191-sqldelight/versions/stable

[image: SQLDelight Support]